# When should Broccoli seeds be sown indoors for spring planting in Minnesota?

Tags: vegetables, transplanting, planting, broccoli

When should I sow my broccoli seeds indoors and when should I transplant outside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look up the last frost date for your zip code [here](http://www.almanac.com/content/frost-chart-united-states). Duluth, for example, has a last frost date of May 21.

Or, as Ed Staub points out in a comment below, for a better picture of the situation go to the original source of the data at the [National Climatic Data Center (1971-2000)](http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/climatenormals/climatenormals.pl?directive=prod_select2&prodtype=CLIM2001&subrnum):

- View the data sheet for your state.
- In the "State and Station Name" column, find the observation station that is nearest and/or most like your location weather-wise.
- In the row for 32°F, read across to the 50% column. (This means that there is a 50% chance of a temperature below 32°F after that date.)
- This date is a reasonable time to transplant broccoli.
- If you are going to [cover the transplants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/841/51) -- which is an effective cabbage looper protection -- then you might be able to transplant a week or two early depending on how heavy your row cover fabric is.

You can transplant broccoli outside a week or two before the last frost date, and start the seed 4 to 6 weeks prior to the transplant date.

About a week before you transplant, start hardening off the plants: first set them outside on a moderate day for a couple of hours, avoiding winds or too much intense sunlight. Then set them outside for longer periods each day. This lets them acclimate to outside conditions so they don't get a sudden shock.

Comment: I'm in zone 4b so I'll probably put them in Feb. 12th along with Cabbage and Parsley. Thanks :)

Comment: @LogicaLunatic: See [this answer](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/a/26/51) for info about what the USDA Zones **don't** tell you -- specifically your last frost date, which is the thing you need to know. Your zone is not relevant in this case. FWIW, I'd start the parsley 2-3 weeks earlier than the broccoli, and the cabbage seeds perhaps a week after the broccoli, though I'd transplant them all at about the same time. (Parsley seeds take a long time to germinate.)

Comment: A [better source for frost dates](http://cdo.ncdc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/climatenormals/climatenormals.pl?directive=prod_select2&prodtype=CLIM2001&subrnum) is to go to the source - the National Climatic Data Center (1971-2000).  With global warming, you have to worry about stale data - I found one site listing dates from 1988, which are likely to be a week or two off.  I don't see where the Old Farmer's Almanac gives a date, and the NCDC tables are a lot richer, too.

Comment: @EdStaub: Thanks, +1 to your comment. I've edited the answer to include that link.